# How to load Kafka topics to HDFS thru Spark streaming and Apache flume

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, flume

I am in learning phase of Kafka.
Using cloudera env.

I have create a topic in Kafka:

```
/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 35.195.113.105:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic airports
```

Producer:

```
/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic airports </home/bitnami/airports.csv
```

I need to copy this topics in HDFS by using Spark Streaming and Flume.

Any ideas or suggestions regarding how to do this.

Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Read this doc first http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html. You will get how to comsumer messages in kafka. And then add the HDFS client code in the foreachRDD function to write the messages to HDFS.